# Gitlab CI saving artifacts

Tags: git, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci, continuous-deployment

**What I am expecting:**

I am trying to generate documentation in my CI script. I want that documentation to be stored in my repository.

I could be understanding the use of artifacts wrong but should this not do the trick?

```
building_documentation:
  stage: buildDoc
  only:
    - develop
  script:
    - npm run arkit
    - npm run doc
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - $CI_PROJECT_DIR/docs
```

The stage runs and completes without any errors. This is the output from the console (docker):
[image]

But after it runs, when I look in my repository there is still no docs folder there containing the documentation generated by `npm run doc`.

In case the information is needed:

- All CI steps pass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Artifact](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pipelines/job_artifacts.html) feature upload job artifacts created by Gitlab runner to the Gitlab server. Then, you can are download them as a single archive using the GitLab UI or the GitLab API.

Artifacts are not pushing back to your repository using `artifacts`. If you want to do this, you need to git add/commit and push back in your repository adding `git` commands in your `.gitlab-ci.yml`

Comment: Are git commands available by default inside the docker image or must I install git in it manually?

Comment: you can use the [docker](https://hub.docker.com/_/docker) image with `:git` tag

Comment: Unfortunately I need to use a container that runs NodeJS. Would you happen to know a solution to how to get git running inside that container?

Comment: I didn't find an image with node and git, you should create your own

Comment: (Updating stale link) https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/job_artifacts.html